# Configure MSVC 2019 in with Qt 5.14.2

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-c++, qt-creator, qt-msvc-addin

1. I have installed Qt 5.14.2 using its binary from the official site. During installation I checked all the options so that nothing misses out.

(I had Visual studio professional 2019 already installed in my system with MSVC 2017)

2. After this I installed Visual Studio 2019 Community for MSVC 2019 by selecting the separate c++ option.

Now when I open cmake file of a qt project, qt tries to configure using msvc 2017 and during configuration it always sends me the following error...

.../.../Visual Studio 2019/professonal/msvc2017/...cl.exe  was unable to execute a simple program.

How to force Qt to use MSVC 2019 to get rid of this error ?

Comment: When you install pre-built binaries from Qt, those binaries (as far as I understand it) are built with an assumption of MSVC compiler toolchain version "baked in". The `qmake.exe` that you received prebuilt is built for MSVC 2017 and nothing else. (Please somebody correct me if I am wrong.) Reference: https://forum.qt.io/topic/111571/qt-already-updated-to-5-14-1-but-why-it-still-uses-msvc-2017-build-tools